# How to open a new screen with additional parameters?

Tags: android

I've read through the FAQ of Android Dev Guid [(http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#opennewscreen)) but I'm not sure how can I open a new screen with additional parameters passed into it.

Let's say I'm going to open screen2, with a variable indicating the current user name so that I could greet the users. Is it possible?

```
Intent i; 
i = new Intent(this, screen2.class);  
//How to pass variable to screen2?
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start Intent by using:

```
Intent foo = new Intent(this, viewContactQuick.class);
        foo.putExtra("id", id);
        this.startActivity(foo);
```

and in onCreate event you can get the `id`

```
id = this.getIntent().getLongExtra("id", 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the putExtra method. Something like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, myNew.class);
i.putExtra("key",keyValue);
```

and on the other side just the getter:

```
this.getIntent().getIntExtra("key"); // If keyvalue was an int
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link you have, lookup for `putExtra`.

The `putExtra` method (from an `Intent` object) is used to pass data between activities.

To send data to another activity, use [putExtra](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra).

To receive data from another activity, use [getExtra](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras())

A [short description to read](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-pass-data-to-activity.html)